# Cassandra multi dc setup using two separate OSE clusters

Tags: cassandra

We have two separate ose clusters one in cmc and another in emc.

OSE cluster - AA in CMC
OSE cluster - BB in EMC

Installed one Cassandra cluster on AA in cmc - Nodes can talk among each other in CMC cluster.

Installed second Cassandra cluster on BB in emc - Nodes can talk among each other in EMC cluster. Both Cassandra nodes from AA in CMC cannot talk to BB in EMC.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify addresses accessible from other DCs as `broadcast_address` ([doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__broadcast_address)) and set `listen_on_broadcast` to true.  Then you need to add the nodes from other DC into list of seed nodes, so they will know each other.

Don't forget about networking - if you listen on public IP, then other could access your servers - use firewall, enable SSL, etc.

P.S. Search for instructions on setting up multi-region cluster in AWS or Azure, and follow instructions (except selecting the snitch)